# Volume in the unit sphere bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider $M$ a riemannian manifold and $A \subset M$. Let $SM$ the sphere bundle of $M$. There exist any relation among the volume of $A$ in $M$ and $\pi^{-1}(A)$ in $SM$?. I guess that as the fibers are $S^{n-1}$
$$
vol_M(A)vol_{\mathbb{R}^n}(S^{n-1}) =  vol(\pi^{-1}(A)).
$$

Remark: If $\omega$ is the volume form in $M$ and $\omega_0$ is the canonical volume form in the fiber $S^{n-1}$ then
$$
\pi^* \omega \wedge \omega_0
$$
is a volume form in $SM$, the canonical volume form of the bundle.

Comment: I don't really understand. Is it a question? Is it a remark? What is exactly your purpose?

Comment: I forget to write '?'

Comment: What's the metric or volume form on $SM$ ?

Comment: The cannonical volume form, I'm adding it

Comment: Do you have an idea to prove this?

Comment: Yes! But I think that is false. I thought use Fubini and the area formula.

Comment: I Think in Fubini Theorem but i also think we can't.

Comment: I'm not sure that what you've written makes sense. $\omega_0$ is a form on the fibers, not on $SM$. Perhaps what you're looking for is the volume form induced by the Sasaki metric on $TM$?

Comment: What is an orthonormal coframe for the sphere bundle?